# Impossible to format my SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd, sata, formatting, diagnostic

I bought my old company laptop (Dell Precision M4800), it's 3 years old and still pretty good. It comes with a SSD (256 GB) and HDD (1 TB). When purchased, my company IT "destroyed everything" (wiped all data?). Win 7 Pro was running on the SSD without issues for 3 years.

Now I took it home with disk emptied and I started installing Windows 10. I wanted to install on SSD but installation froze for ~2h and then failed. I already set the Bios in AHCI mode, and tried with removing other drives during installation. I tried formatting the disk myself with `diskpart` before installation (shift + F10), all went well (convert GPT, create partition), except format command which fails with no useful information.

After 2 days trying to format it, including from a Ubuntu USB boot, I could not make it and decided to try to install on HDD. It went fine in less than 15 mn and I have now Win 10 running on my HDD.

I downloaded many drive tools to analyze it (Minitool partition wizard, CrystalDiskInfo, Hard Disk Sentinel) but they found nothing wrong:

- surface scan is ok
- all attributed ok (no read only etc..)
- health status good

With any of these tools, the format command is the one failing. After failing, the disk disappear from windows and diskpart, I need to reboot the computer to see it back.

Finally I tried DBAN to erase all on that drive just in case, but it was way too slow to wait to complete (estimate > 2000h).

The disk details are as follow:

```
           Model : LITEONIT LCS-256L9S-11 2.5 7mm 256GB
        Firmware : HC8110D
   Serial Number : TW03YYV35508544N5307
       Disk Size : 256.0 GB (8.4/137.4/256.0/256.0)
     Buffer Size : Unknown
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 500118192
   Rotation Rate : ---- (SSD)
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ATA8-ACS
   Minor Version : ATA/ATAPI-7 T13 1532D version 4a
   Transfer Mode : SATA/600 | SATA/600
  Power On Hours : 2242 hours
  Power On Count : 893 count
     Temperature : Unknown
   Health Status : Good
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., AAM, 48bit LBA, NCQ, TRIM, DevSleep
       APM Level : ----
       AAM Level : FE00h [OFF]
    Drive Letter :
```

I have also unmounts the drive and mount it back just in case, but not much possibilities here (like changing cable etc...) as there is only one slot.

Do you think the disk is dead ?
Do you know another way of "saving" it ?

Thanks to those reading to the end :-)

[image: DBAN process]
[image: Drive unmounted]

#### EDIT

CrystalDiskInfo screenshot

[image]

#### EDIT 2

After updating all drivers possible, I have no more ideas.

I consider the drive to be dead. However it is still mounted so if anyone has suggestions I can try new manipulations. Also if I have the opportunity to mount the SSD onto another laptop, I will try that and update this topic.

Windows is now installed on the HDD and I start using the computer normally.

#### FINAL EDIT

One year later (20th April 2019), I wanted to create a partition on the HD to install Ubuntu, I realize the SSD was up and running. I could format it (from Windows) and later install Ubuntu on it.

I am not sure what happened in the meantime.

Comment: Using DBAN on managed flash memory is pointless. Please provide a screenshot of CrystalDiskInfo. Do note that Dell’s OEM SSDs are pretty terrible and a (superior) 256 GB SSD is quite inexpensive these days.

Comment: Indeed it does not look like the more reliable SSD on the market... however it was working perfectly until it was cleaned up, so I wonder if it was due to a bad operation and if I can revert it. CrystalDiskInfo screeshot added.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: I tried it (on disk 0 - the SSD), it's going ok until the format command (NTFS) which is just hanging and then failing (with the disk led continuously lighted ON for ~10mn before it fails)

Comment: Format with command in diskpart:  `format fs=NTFS quick`

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary with SMART. Do you have another PC you can use the SSD in?

Comment: @DanielB unfortunately no, I can't check with another PC

Comment: @Biswapriyo thanks but I tried already:
`DISKPART> format fs=NTFS quick
    0 percent completed
DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
See the System Event Log for more information.`

Comment: I would try and resetting the drive in every possible manner; 0 the drive and possibly a firmware flash.  Then run tests on it to see if your can reproduce the errors/faults.  I suspect it is a configuration issue.  Try mounting the SSD using a Linux LiveCD and playing with it in a raw state in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all apparent reasons, the drive *is* dead. Have it recycled the proper way and let it be forgotten. Probably a memory chip gone bad or a line cut off. It's not so uncommon, but it still ruins your day. And this is why we still use RAID in the age of SSD drives that have no moving parts. They still fail, and in certain cases much less gracefully than their mechanical counterparts.

Comment: I am also considering it dead. I should buy a new one instead.